# Android cache image with Picasso and OkHttpClient

Tags: android

i'm currently using `picasso` library to load photo or imges from network such as internet. in this library document i can found: this library cache photo after load. for have this ability after download `OkHttpClient` and add this library into project i'm paste this below class to use that

```
public class PicassoCache {
    private static Picasso picassoInstance = null;
    private PicassoCache (Context context) {
        Downloader downloader   = new OkHttpDownloader(context, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
        builder.downloader(downloader);
        picassoInstance = builder.build();
    }
    public static Picasso getPicassoInstance (Context context) {
        if (picassoInstance == null) {
            new PicassoCache(context);
            return picassoInstance;
        }
        return picassoInstance;
    }
}
```

and use this class such as:

```
PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(G.context).load(item.getAvatar()).into(uiFiller.img_category_main_avatar);
```

unfortunatelly i get this error in compile:

```
Error:(15, 35) java: C:\Users\mahdi\IdeaProjects\EitaaPro\src\ir\tsms\EitaaPro\Libraries\PicassoCache.java:15: cannot access com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
class file for com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient not found
```

import Jar library successfull into project, why i get error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The core of the library was split up into two artifacts with the latest release. If you're copying jars around you need to use the 'jar-with-dependencies' version @ http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.okhttp%7Cokhttp%7C1.2.0%7Cjar

Using an artifact tool is highly recommended (Maven/Gradle/Ivy/etc.) since it'll pull this automatically.

Comment: i get this error for all version :  for example, No files were downloaded for com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.0